# Ignore the Ad on Specific Categories

Tags: categories, single

I don't want to display the ad in a few posts for a specific category (cat1, cat2).

Here's the ad code to display the ad on single.php

```
<?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/ads/below-header' ); ?>
```

Comment: What is the ad you're referring to? Not everybody uses or knows how your theme works so you need to share this information. E.g. my site doesn't have a `template-parts` folder and does not have advertisements, so I don't know what `template-parts/ads/below-header` contains or where that line is located

Comment: check https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/in_category/ and the examples therein